# Regex Statement in VSCode snippet for removing file extension

Tags: regex, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'd like to create a VS-Code snippet for importing css into a react component. If I'm using the snippet in "MyComponent.tsx", then I'd like the snippet to import the associated css file for the component:

```js
import "./MyComponent.css";
```

The component and it's css will always be located in the same directory.

I thought that the following snippet would be able to do this:

```json
//typescriptreact.json
      "import componet css": {
        "prefix": "icss2",
        "body": [
          "import \"./${1:$TM_FILENAME/^(.+)(\.[^ .]+)?$/}.css\";"
        ],
        "description": ""
      },
```

But this results in:

```js
import "./MyComponent.tsx/^(.+)([^ .]+)?$/.css";
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"import componet css": {
    "prefix": "icss2",
    "body": [
      "import \"./${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.*)\\..*/$1/}.css\";"
    ],
    "description": ""
}
```

The `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` variable holds the file name without the path, and the `^(.*)\\..*` regex matches and captures all up to the last `.` while just matching the extension, and only the captured part remains due to the `$1` replacement pattern (that refers to Group 1 value).

Answer (score 0):

```
"import component css": {
    "prefix": "icss2",
    "body": [
        "import \"./${TM_FILENAME_BASE}.css\";"
    ],
    "description": ""
}
```

> `TM_FILENAME_BASE` The filename of the current document without its
> extensions

from [snippet variables documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables).

So there is no need to remove the `.tsx` extension via a transform - it is already done for you.

---

The more interesting question is what if you have a file like

`myComponent.next.tsx`  // what should the final result be?

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` will only take off the final `.tsx` resulting in `import "./myComponent.next.css";`

@Wiktor's results in `import "./myComponent.css";`

Which is correct in your case?  Is something like `myComponent.next.tsx` a possible case for you?  If not just use `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` with no need for a transform.